# @SqlResultSetMapping binding inner class to targetclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1, sqlresultsetmapping

In my project, I have created a view that contains multiple joins. The following is part of the query from the view.

```
a.id,
b.object1,
b.object2,
b.object3,
case when (c.type = 'qrt' then c.object4 else b.object4) end object4, 
case when(c.type = 'qrt' then c.object5 else b.object5) end object5 
from A a
left join B b on b.a_id = a.id
left join c c on c.b_id = b.id
```

This query will return the data as follows:

```
id   object1    object2    object3    object4     object5
1    a1         b1         c1         d1          e1
1    a1         b1         c1         d2          e2
2    a2         b2         c2         d3          e3
2    a2         b2         c2         d4          d5
```

I want to map the result with the following POJO class

```
public class Example{

private Integer id;
private String object1;
private String object2;
private String object3;
List<InnerExample> innerExample;
}


public class InnerExample{
private String object4;
private String object5;
}
```

In UI data will be displayed in a table with pagination like below.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table >
<tr>
<td rowspan = 2>id</td>
<td rowspan = 2>name</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object1</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object2</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object3</td>
<td>object4</td>
<td>object5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>object4</td>
<td>object5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan = 2>id</td>
<td rowspan = 2>name</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object1</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object2</td>
<td rowspan = 2>object3</td>
<td>object4</td>
<td>object5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>object4</td>
<td>object5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am using Spring JPA and I didn't find an approach to directly map the result to the Example POJO.

Can anyone please help me...

Comment: Since your POJO's are not entities, I think you have to do the mapping manually, tough it is tedious. And requires 3 comparators. Even with projection, the same is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring boot JPA you can directly convert your query results into a class from any of the repository classes that you have written.

> @Repository
> public interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<BEntity, Integer> {
>
> ```
> @Query("SELECT new path.from.src.folder.Example(" + 
>        "a.id, b.object1,b.object2, b.object3, " + 
>        "new path.from.src.folder.Example.InnerExample(" +
>        "case when(c.type='qrt' then c.object4 else b.object4) end object4,"+ 
>        "case when(c.type='qrt' then c.object5 else b.object5) end object5" + 
>        "))" + 
>        "from AEntity as a " + 
>        "left join BEntity as b on b.a_id = a.id " + 
>        "left join c c on c.b_id = b.id ")
> Example customQueryJoiningAandBandCtable();
> ```
>
> }

Also, add the following constructors in the Example and InnerExample class.

> ```
> public Example(Integer id, String object1, String object2, String object3, InnerExample innerExample) {
>     this.id = id;
>     this.object1 = object1;
>     this.object2 = object2;
>     this.object3 = object3;
>     this.innerExample = innerExample;   }
>
> public InnerExample(String object4, String object5) {
>     this.object4 = object4;
>     this.object5 = object5;   
> }
> ```

Please keep in mind in here I have used List instead of InnerExample as I am quite unsure how the query is working and is giving list output. But you can modify accordingly.

Comment: I need List<InnerExample> and I can't use JPA repository class. I have to do it with NativeSQLQuery and using EntityManager. If I have to use just an object I can do that but not sure about List<InnerExample>.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still unable to understand the query.    --------                                             
 case when (c.type = 'qrt' then c.object4 else b.object4) end object4, 
case when(c.type = 'qrt' then c.object5 else b.object5) end object5                                     -------------- This will just return InnerExample not a List<InnerExample>. How is List coming into picture? The only thing I can think of is the whole query returning List<Example> instead of Example.

Comment: I edited a question with the SQL query result. Hope this will help to understand the question.

Comment: This is what I was talking about. If our query result is like this and then SQL will treat this as List<Example> it will not treat results with the same id in a single answer. Think of it this way, you can cast each row of the answer into a POJO. If you still need InnerExample as a list then either you need to change the query or modify results after the query is executed.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I have to do it manually but I was thinking if anyone has customized the @SqlResultSetMapping, so I can take help from them.